# Can You Enforce A Code Freeze In Git?

Tags: git

Currently, when we have a code freeze in SVN we turn on a commit hook that rejects commits to our frozen branch.

e.g. http://www.weblogism.com/item/235/subversion-commit-pre-hook-to-enforce-a-code-freeze

Is it possible to do something similar in Git?

i.e. can you prevent a push to a remote branch?

If you can, how would you make those changes on a private hosted GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an [update hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the remote to prevent anyone from accessing a branch you want to protect.

I'm not personally familiar with GitHub, though.  Hopefully someone will come along with an answer for you soon.

Comment: github has [hooks api](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/), that could do it. or not, haven't tried.

Comment: This is a good answer for a question about *git* but not very helpful for *github* which doesn't provide equivalent functionality.

Comment: For Github there's now [merge freeze](https://github.com/marketplace/merge-freeze)